# When are Attribute instances created?

Tags: .net, attributes

Are attributes instantiated at the same time as instances of the class to which they are applied?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Attributes are loaded when the `Type.GetCustomAttributes()` is called.  If you just instantiate the class or even get the type, the attributes are not yet loaded.

See this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling AttributeLoadTest.TestStatic():");
        AttributeLoadTest.TestStatic();
        Console.WriteLine("Loading class");
        var x = new AttributeLoadTest();
        Console.WriteLine("Loading type..");
        var t = typeof (AttributeLoadTest);
        Console.WriteLine("Calling GetCustomAttributes()");
        var ats = t.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    }
}

[ConsoleTest]
class AttributeLoadTest
{
    public static void TestStatic()
    {

    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class ConsoleTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ConsoleTestAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleTestAttribute Constructor");
    }
}
```

This prints out:

> Calling AttributeLoadTest.TestStatic():
>
> Loading class
>
> Loading type..
>
> Calling GetCustomAttributes()
>
> ConsoleTestAttribute Constructor

So calling a static method, instantiating the class, getting the type, does not instantiate the attribute.  Calling `GetCustomAttributes()` does.

Comment: I've just come across this behavior myself, and am wondering what the rationale behind this is? Why would a type's attributes not be pre-loaded like the rest of a Type's object graph?

Comment: @Martaver, delayed loading is a very common practice in software development.  It's generally more efficient to not load things until you need them.  It's always more efficient if you usually never need them.

Comment: @SamualNeff Thanks for replying, I understanding the purpose of lazy loading, but I was actually more interested in WHY attributes would need to be lazy loaded, as opposed to loaded at the same time as the parent Type. With a bit of digging I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/417302/535930

Comment: Is this true? Is an attribute not bound to a type before or just after run time starts? I am new to .net however I noticed after inserting a breakpoint in my code it looks to me that the custom attribute class I have defined is getting instantiated before my any of my test code gets executed.

Comment: @Stewart, it's true, I didn't fake the console output. :-)  I rechecked it now since this post is a few years old, and got the same results with .NET 4.0.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Humm could it be the JIT? Perhaps in my project that JIT is initializing the type at a different time. Still does not explain why I am seeing the constructor of my custom attribute class be called long before I call 'GetCustomAttributeData()'. Maybe I am calling some other method in my code that causes this to run but I could not possibly imagine where I am doing that.

Comment: @Stewart, add code in your constructor to print out a stack trace. If you run the exact code above, do you get the same results posted or something different?

Answer (score -2):

No. Attributes are bound to the type and thus instantiated when the type is loaded.

Comment: type is loaded, not instance?

Comment: No, attributes are not loaded when the type is loaded.  They aren't loaded until they're actually needed.

Comment: Strange. Thank you for testing. Now I wonder whether (i) GetCustomAttributes generates new attribute objects every time when it is called and (ii) the attribute classes are loaded earlier.

Comment: @JohnB, a new instance is created every time you call `GetCustomAttributes()`.

Comment: Thank you for doing this VERY interesting research.

Comment: @JohnB, yeah, I was surprised at the answer actually.  Sometimes the only way to know for sure is to test.